# Match Latin words which not in the hook

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter words which is not in the "[ ]".

Why is this not working?

```
[^\[][\u0000-\u024F]+[^\]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your expression is not working is that it matches all text *inside* brackets as well as outside.

This is the best I've been able to do:

```
/(?:^|])[^[]+/g
```

It includes the `]`s in the match because look-behind is not allowed:

http://regexr.com/3c515

If look-behind were allowed, this would be the ticket:

```
/(?:^|(?<=]))[^[]+/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/lK9tS7/3

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually works, but how I can match only the Latin words outside the brackets?

Comment: Not sure what that means, but try changing the `^[` to `\u0000-\u005A\u005C-\u024F`.

Answer (score 0):

Because this will match `[\u0000-\u024F]+` and 2 character which will be matches by `[^\[]`. If you want to your regex engine match the whole of pattern you need to use start and end anchors in your regex :

```
/^[^\[][\u0000-\u024F]+[^\]]$/m
```

But this will work if your string is contain words in each line, which is not a proper way.

As a better way you can use negative look arounds :

```
(?<!\[)[\u0000-\u024F]+(?!\])
```

Comment: This is the test line: [link](http://regexr.com/3c4vr). Seem like it's still not working. How can I match only the "Good morning" words?